# How can I get python to get exactly the bytes written to the standard output when running with subprocess.run?

Tags: python, windows

The problem I have is the following: in a subprocess (on Windows), someone is writing something as:

`print("line1\r\nline2\r\nline3\n")`

and for some reason additional `\r` chars end up in the stream being written.

I'm running in binary mode (`text=False`) -- which I thought would let me get exactly the same bytes written, but I just can get it unless the user just writes bytes to `sys.stdout.buffer`, which isn't really feasible given that the codebase has `print` in the code which I'd like to capture properly (just not with the additional chars there).

Below is a sample code on what I was expecting to work (but doesn't in practice and I'm not really sure why):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    if "-" not in sys.argv[1:]:
        import subprocess

        result = subprocess.run(
            [sys.executable, __file__, "-"], capture_output=True, text=False
        )
        output = result.stdout
        assert (
            output == b"line1\r\nline2\r\nline3\nline1\r\nline2\r\nline3\n"
        ), f"Found: {output!r}"

    else:
        sys.stdout.write("line1\r\nline2\r\nline3\n")
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(b"line1\r\nline2\r\nline3\n")
```

Also, depending on whether I'm using a real terminal or running from the IDE, the contents written are different.

When running from the IDE (tested in PyDev and in PyCharm) I get:

`AssertionError: Found: b'line1\r\r\nline2\r\r\nline3\r\nline1\r\nline2\r\nline3\n'`

and when running from the terminal I get:

`AssertionError: Found: b'line1\r\nline2\r\nline3\nline1\r\r\nline2\r\r\nline3\r\n'`

-- notice that in the terminal additional `\r` chars are added to the contents written to `sys.stdout.buffer` part, whereas in the IDE additional `\r` chars are added to the `sys.stdout` part.

Comment: The "bytes written" include the `\r`, there's nothing you can do about it.  The conversion of `\n` to `\r\n` occurs in the program you're running, or more specifically its runtime library.

Comment: As a workaround, you may want to do this before writing to `sys.stdout`: `import msvcrt, os; msvcrt.setmode(1, os.O_BINARY)`. After that, use `sys.stdout.buffer.write. I can't verify this, I don't have easy access to Windows with Python.

Comment: This looks like a bug in Python `subprocess`, you may want to report it in the Python bug tracker.

Comment: @pts it's NOT a bug in Python or `subprocess`.  If you file a bug that's exactly what you'll be told.

Comment: @Mark Ransom, Ok, so, you said that the `\r` is being added in python in `sys.stdout.write` (or in `sys.stdout.buffer.write`) depending on the case (and the issue isn't really on `subprocess.run`) right?

Comment: I can confirm that with `sys.stdout.buffer.write` and the msvrct hack I get the exact bytes, but it doesn't fix the part that writes with `sys.stdout`. Is there some workaround for that so that both work?

Comment: I guess one could monkey-patch `sys.stdout` and then encode what's written exactly to `sys.stdout.buffer`. It's highly annoying that this needs to be changed in the target python program and not controlled by the caller though.

Comment: @FabioZadrozny: The Windows libc (MSVCRT, UCRT etc.) in the target program controls to \n --> \r\n transformation on stdout (and other streams). It is enabled at program startup, and it can be disabled with `setmode(..., O_BINARY)`. There is no standard mechansim for the calling program to start the target program with the transformation disabled. This is a Windows process and libc limitation unrelated to Python, all programming languages and interpreters are affected.

Comment: Yes, I get that it's something from Windows now. I wouldn't call it a libc limitation given that it has an API to disable it though -- It's a bit annoying that python doesn't give the option disable that by default to do the "right" thing from the outside with some env var or command line flag. @Mark Ranson thank you for the insights on understanding how it works. If you'd like to create an answer I can accept it -- otherwise the answer can be seen in this comment thread ;)

Comment: I've been thinking of leaving an answer, but it needs more fleshing out than I have time for at the moment.

Comment: Tangentially, the code you put inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` should be absolutely trivial. The condition is only useful when you `import` this code; if all the useful functionality is excluded when you `import`, you will never want to do that anyway. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/69778466/874188

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations, you've discovered the difference between text mode and binary mode!

In the beginning was the teletype.  A big mechanical device, it had a moving head to put letters on paper.  To go to a new line, you needed two operations: a carriage return to move the head to the left side, and a line feed to advance the paper by one line.  These two operations were initiated by two different characters, unsurprisingly called Carriage Return (`\r`) and Line Feed (`\n`).  The return had to come first to give the head enough time to return all the way to the left before it needed to print again.

When the Unix OS was invented, they decided they only wanted a single character to mark the end of a line, and they chose the Line Feed.  For those devices that still required the two-character sequence like a Teletype, they had the driver convert every `\n` to `\r\n` as it was being sent.  So programs written for Unix never had to worry about `\r`, it was handled automatically.

The C language was written on and for Unix, so it adopted the same convention of using a single `\n` to mark the end of a line.

When C was ported to other operating systems with different line ending conventions, they had a conundrum.  Do they make every program change its print statements depending on which OS it's running on?  They had the clever idea instead to let the I/O library do what Unix was doing, converting `\n` to `\r\n` automatically.  So that you could still have binary files where every byte was exactly as you wrote it, they came up with text files where the conversion was applied and binary files where it was not.  Since output was expected to be text, the input and output files were defaulted to text mode.

The important thing to note here is that the conversion is occurring in the program that's generating the output.  And unless that program has gone out of its way to override the default, it's going to output `\r\n` automatically, out of its control.

Since Python was originally written in C, it maintains some of the behaviors of C.  One of those is the automatic conversion of `\n` in text mode.